# Word for "getting careless and slacking"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns, idioms, adjectives

Can you suggest some words which can describe a person who is starting to get careless and who slacks, or the very action of becoming careless? A person who was efficiently and elaborately doing their job but with time started to be careless and their performance started to deteriorate.

Comment: "It" cannot be used for people. (With the exception of babies, whose job it *is* to be careless and slacking.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

> [***complacent***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complacent) :
>     marked by self-satisfaction especially when accompanied by unawareness of actual dangers or deficiencies
>   :    marked by complacency
>
> - The strong economy has made people complacent.
> - We have grown too complacent over the years.
> - We can't afford to be complacent about illiteracy.

The person in your question would have become *complacent* in their job.
*When Susan first started, she did her job admirably, but she has recently become complacent and it's starting to show.*

Answer (score 6):

Consider **[coasting](http://www.yourdictionary.com/coast)**

> to continue without serious effort, letting one's past efforts carry one along

There is also an idiom **[phoning it in](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=phone%20it%20in)**

> Perform an act in a perfunctory, uncommitted fashion, as if it didn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider:

> **LACKADAISICAL** *adjective* : feeling or showing a lack of interest or enthusiasm:  lacking life, spirit, or zest :  languid

from m-w.com

Comment: This answer seems to be lacking a citation of its source. Please always give credit to sources.

Comment: @MετάEd Thanks for the prompt.  Imagine my chagrin when I had forgotten to cite "lackadaisical," of all words.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a noun, [*slacker*](https://www.google.ca/search?q=slacker+definition) might fit the bill:

> A person who avoids work or effort.